# How to stop form overflowing the footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the contact section increase size dynamically according to page size and textbox size. Right now it overflows the footer and even the whole page at a certain viewport. My goal is to make it responsive and to not overflow.

Here are some examples of what happens with the current setup:

[image: here's what happens]

[image: and here]

I would really appreciate insight into how to make this responsive such that the contact section doesn't overflow my footer.

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: linear-gradient(#000, #383838);
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

section h1 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}

article {
  font-size: 35px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: space-around;
  row-gap: 20px;
  height: fit-content;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 70vh;
}

#imie {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

#nazwisko {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

#email {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

#tytul {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

#tresc {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

#wyslij {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#wyslij:active {
  transform: translateY(5px);
}

form input,
textarea {
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #EEEEEE;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  font-size: 2vw;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #DEE8F4;
}

form div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 70vw;
}
```

```html
<section id="contact">
  <h1>KONTAKT</h1>
  <article>
    <form>
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="imie" name="nazwisko" placeholder="imię">
        <input type="text" id="nazwisko" name="nazwisko" placeholder="nazwisko">
      </div>
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="e-mail">
      <input type="text" id="tytul" name="tytul" placeholder="tytuł wiadomości">
      <textarea id="tresc" name="tresc" placeholder="treść"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" id="wyslij" name="wyslij" value="wyślij">
    </form>
  </article>
</section>
<footer>
  <p>DESPISE 2023 &copy</p>
</footer>
</main>
```

Comment: You do not have a main element, only a `</main>` You likely want to open the main and close it BEFORE the footer

Answer (score 0):

Since your form height depends on the viewport height, it will be smaller than the height specified in the following code:

```
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 70vh;
}
```

You can update the code as shown below:

```
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 70vw;
  min-height: 70vh;
}
```

Here is a sample link: https://codepen.io/camel2243/pen/poOXLpZ

After the modification, the code works properly.

Comment: omg i'm so dumb, I forgot that I've put something like that in my code. thanks so much for your help!

Comment: If you click `[<>]` or "Copy snippet to answer" from OP's question, you can post a [mcve] as an answer so ppl do not have to leave SO to see the running code. SO does not handle cookies or window storage but it can handle most other code

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I will make sure to include it next time. Your feedback is greatly appreciated.